# how can i change this arduino code to make it work?

Tags: arduino

I've been working on making a servo work as a compass, im using an arduino Duemilanove and an HMC6352 Compass Module. When I try to program it the adrduino programer says that Wire.send has been renamed to Wire.write and Wire.receive had been renamed to Wire.read so I've changed them but it then tells me error compilling. I'm not sure what else to do to it. please help if you have any answers.

this is the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// Pins
#define SDA 4 // analog
#define SCL 5 // analog
#define servoPointerPin 10

// Controllers
Servo servoPointer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 4800 );
  delay( 500 );
  setupCompass();
  setupServo();
  Serial.println( "Setup Complete" );
}

void setupCompass()
{
  Wire.begin();
}

void setupServo()
{
  servoPointer.attach( servoPointerPin );
  positionServo( &servoPointer, 50 );
}

void positionServo( Servo* pServo, int position )
{
  int currentPosition = pServo->read();
  if( currentPosition != position )
    pServo->write( position );
}

int lastHeading = -1;

bool getCurrentHeading( int& reading )
{
  int compassAddress = 0x42 >> 1;
  Wire.beginTransmission( compassAddress );
  Wire.write( 'A' );
  Wire.endTransmission();

  delay(10);  
  Wire.requestFrom( compassAddress, 2 );
  while( Wire.available() < 2 )
    delay(10);

  int newReading = Wire.read();
  newReading = newReading << 8;
  newReading += Wire.read();
  newReading /= 10;
  bool result = ( lastHeading == -1 ) ? true : ( abs( newReading - lastHeading ) > 2 );
  reading = newReading;
  if( result )
    lastHeading = reading;  
  return result;
}

void loop()
{
  int heading = 0;
  if( getCurrentHeading(heading) )
    PositionNeedle( heading );
}

void PositionNeedle( const int currentHeading )
{
  int bearing = -currentHeading;
  if( bearing < 0 )
    bearing += 360;

  Serial.print( "Bearing=" );
  Serial.print( bearing, DEC );
  float minSweep = 80.0f;
  float sweepRange = 145.0f - minSweep;
  int servoPosition = (int)(sweepRange - (bearing / 360.0f * sweepRange) + minSweep);
  Serial.print( " Servo=" );
  Serial.println( servoPosition, DEC );
  positionServo( &servoPointer, servoPosition );
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting at compile?

Comment: this is all it says after Error Compilling and i have no idea what it means:
In file included from /Users/makers/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:235,
                 from compass.ino:10:
/Users/makers/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h:45: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/Users/makers/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h:46: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it's because you are redefining SDA and SCL. So lines 45 and 46 of pins_arduino.h are having trouble.

From pins_arduino.h:

```
45   static const uint8_t SDA = 18;
46   static const uint8_t SCL = 19;
```

You are incidentally changing these lines with your #define statements. #define does not work like variable declaration, it actually replaces any instances of the first argument with the second argument pre-compilation. So the compiler comes to those lines in the pins_arduino.h file and now sees:

```
45   static const uint8_t 4 = 18;
46   static const uint8_t 5 = 19;
```

Which is what is throwing the error because you cannot define '4' or '5' as a variable.

Comment: ok so i changed the SDA 4 to 18 and the SCL 5 to 19 but it still says error compilling, is there more to those lines that i have to change?

Comment: I added a bit of information to my answer above to show what is actually happening to cause the error. What are you trying to do with those two statements? It looks like you are trying to change the SDA and SCL pins, which you cannot do. Your SDA and SCL pins are defined in hardware and you should just use those correct pins and remove the #define statements which are causing other unavoidable errors.

Comment: these solutions dont seem to help so i don't know if there are other problems to this code but these other things aren't helping for some reason

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? Can you update your answer to show your changed code?

Comment: ok so i had some help with programing it and i would verify it and it said Done Uploading so then i actually uploaded it and it said: Binary sketch problem uploading to board. See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions size: 7,804 bytes (of a 30,720 byte maximum)                                avrdude: stk500_recv(): programer is not responding

Comment: i dont know how to send you my code now that its changed a bit.

Comment: It looks like your code is compiling fine now. The original issue is fixed if it is compiling. Now your programmer is having trouble. "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programer is not responding". How are you connecting your computer to your board?

Comment: its just like a little cord that hooks up from the board to the usb if you want a little more specific, the company is Monoprice. the print on the cord says High speed cable 2.0 revision.

Comment: Are you able to upload a simple blink sketch?

Comment: Which arduino are you using?

Comment: im using an arduino Duemilanove Atmega328. do you know why the compass part heats up so much? its the right voltage and everything but it can burn you to the touch